# HTML <div> height not expanding with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having problem with populating an HTML div with dynamic content. When dynamic data loads inside the div, its height is not expanding to fit the content. 
The jquery code for dynamic content is:

```
$('.width_3_quarter').append('<h2>Selected Groups</h2>');
                            for(var i=0; i<userGroups.length; i++)
                            {   
                                var div=$('<div id="data"'+i+' style="display:block;">'+userGroups[i]+'</div> ');
                                $('.width_3_quarter').append(div);
                            }

                            var selCat=$('<div id="selectedCat"><span style="font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;">Groups Selected </span></div>');
                            var label=$('<label style="margin-top:-1px; margin-bottom:0px;position:absolute;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Available Groups </label>');

                            var selectedData=$('<div id="myData"></div>');

                            var select=$('<select id="grpSelect" name="grpSelect" multiple="multiple"> </select>');
                            for(var i=0;i<listGroups.length; i++)
                            {
                                var option=$('<option value="'+listGroups[i]+'">'+listGroups[i]+'</option>');
                                select.append(option);
                            }


                            var button=$('<input type="button" value="submit" id="valSubmit" onclick="addGrp();"/>');

                    selCat.append(selectedData);
                $('.width_3_quarter').append(label);
                selCat.prepend(button);
                $('.width_3_quarter').append(select);
                $('.width_3_quarter').append(selCat);
```

Here, the data is getting loaded from a static array with string values.

The html div is as:

```
<div class="module width_3_quarter" style="clear:both;">
```

When I put static data inside the div, it is expanding to fit the size of the content. However, its not the case with dynamic data.
The CSS is:

```
.width_3_quarter {
width: 73%;
    margin-right: 0;
    min-height: 462px;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #1F1F20;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    line-height: 36px;
    font-size: 18px;


}
```

[image: Screen shot for the div]

How can I control my div's height to fit the size of the dynamic content?

Comment: yeah please create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Creating Mr_Green. It little slow today. Taking time to run

Answer (score 2):

instead of `overflow:hidden` do a `overflow:auto`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the min-height to 100%:

```
min-height:100%;
```

Comment: Can't do that. My div is initially empty. Doing this will show my div height to 100%. I want it to be of height 462px initially.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing this

```
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

From experience you have to specify the axis you want overflow to work on sometimes

Comment: It is also showing the scrollbar when the data exceeds the min-height specified.

Comment: if it is CSS, there should be `:`(_colon_) instead of `=` (_equal_).

Comment: @Mr_Green Oh yeah sorry about that I'm moving between different languages and did it without realising